# Strange code being appened to url on page load

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Something weird is happening with my page when it loads.

It seems to always append #.UB7lYmMk67s to the end of the url, which wont look good to visitors.

I have confirmed its not my javascript code or custom PHP include functions.

Has anyone got any ideas what might be causing this?

You can see it here:

http://www.caketopper.co.uk/2012/animal-cake-toppers/christening-bear

You'll notice as soon as the page is done loading this junk gets added to the end of it.

My .htaccess seems fine, but here it is anyway:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^cake-toppers/([a-z\-]+)$ topper-page.php?topperurlname=$1
RewriteRule ^animal-cake-toppers/([a-z\-]+)$ topper-page.php?topperurlname=$1
RewriteRule ^people-cake-toppers/([a-z\-]+)$ topper-page.php?topperurlname=$1
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: It is javascript. I don't get the anchor with javascript disabled.

Comment: Are you using google analytics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using "AddThis". See their [Click Tracking FAQ](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381252-click-tracking).

(seems it appends a `#.UB7ng88cJxk` when I go to that support link).

If you want to disable it, it says to include this script in your AddThis code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var addthis_config = {
     data_track_clickback: false 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It was actually: "data_track_addressbar":true causing it, i changed it to false and it worked.